# How to use "oneOf" in this schema?

Tags: javascript, json, json.net, schema, jsonschema

I'd like to have either A or B, but not both (mutual exclusive.)

I have to use whatever is avaliable in Draft 3, even though it says 4 on the top. Reason being, when using array for "required", it throws an error that it can't convert an array to a boolean. If I remove arrays without putting that I'm using draft 4 [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Extensions]::IsValid does not validate. It returns "true" willy nilly.

Yes, I have to use an obsolete Newtonsoft.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "description": "",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "SearchCriteria": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "minItems": 1,
      "required": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "A": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "pattern": "^[^\\s]*$"
          },
          "B": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "pattern": "^[^\\s]*$",
              "enum": ["One", "Two"]
            },
            "minItems": 1
          },
          "C": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true,
            "minLength": 2
          },
          "D": {
            "type": "array",
            "required": true,
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "anyOf", "allOf" and "oneOf" were added in Draft 4.  See the official Draft 4 changes here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#appendix-A.  I'm not sure that core Newtonsoft every supported Draft 4 though, I can't even find "oneof" in it's source code using a [github search](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/search?q=oneof).

Comment: Is there a way to do this in draft 4 without using an array?

Comment: You were looking in the wrong repo @dbc, you wanted https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/search?q=oneOf

Comment: The way `required` works for draft-04 is different to 03, hence your issue with validation passing when you want it to fail. For draft-04, `required` goes at the same level as `properties`, and its value must be an array of the required values.

Comment: @Relequestual - I'm looking in the correct repo.  Op can **only** use Json.NET and not any additional tools such as Json.NET Schema.  That was explained in a comment which seems to have been deleted.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know it was previously bundled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draft 3 does *not* support `OneOf` or any of the likes as [@dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) mentioned in a comment.

`[Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema]` uses draft 3 to prase the JSON file. Hence why it was ignoring `OneOf` AND throwing an error for `"required"` being an array. In draft 3, `"required"` can only be a `boolean`.

To overcome this, use `[Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema]` to parse the Schema as a string and `[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]` to parse the JSON as a string, and `[Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.SchemaExtensions]` to validate isntead of `[Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Extensions]`.